# Adding removing from array is resulting in an empty array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I run the following:

```
urls = [];
console.log(urls);
$('body').on('click', '#loadImages .card span', function () {
 var src = $(this).parent().find("img").attr('src');
 $(this).hasClass('checked') ? urls.splice(urls.indexOf(src), 1) : urls.push('<div class="card"><img class="img-fluid" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="' + src+ '"></div>');
 $(this).toggleClass('checked');
 console.log(urls);
});
```

In console I get:

```
["<div class="card"><img class="img-fluid" onerror="…ns/7/73/Xinhai_Revolution_in_Shanghai.jpg"></div>"]

[]
```

How does the array gets emptied?

I am basically trying to add/remove images to an array

Comment: Probably from: `urls.splice(urls.indexOf(src), 1)`

Comment: @KevinJantzer what should I do to check it?

Comment: @KevinJantzer updated the question as I was missing the reset of the urls array

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).hasClass('checked')
```

If that evaluated to true, `urls` only element gets spliced. No other way.

Comment: @rob.m Why are you doing that BTW ?

Comment: as I stated on the question, I am basically trying to add/remove images to an array, and i need to push that array later

Answer (score 0):

You can step through your code easier by changing this line

### From:

```
$(this).hasClass('checked') ? urls.splice(urls.indexOf(src), 1) : urls.push('<div class="card"><img class="img-fluid" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="' + src+ '"></div>');`
```

### To:

```
// if the clicked item has the class "checked"
if( $(this).hasClass('checked') ){

  console.log("removing url from array")

  // determine if the url is already in the array of urls
  var urlIndex = urls.indexOf(src)

  // -1 means it was not found (0 would be first in array)
  if( urlIndex > -1 ){
    console.log("url exists, remove it from array"
    urls.splice(urlIndex, 1)
  }
}else{
   console.log("adding url to array")
   urls.push('<div class="card"><img class="img-fluid" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="' + src+ '"></div>');
}
```

### However...

The urls will never be removed from the array because you are looking for the literal src `.attr('src')` but you are storing a custom html string `<div class...`

Comment: oh ok it's a bit more, will try again, the previous code you posted was working but duplicating the img

Comment: ok it fixed the empty one but for some reason, the second time i run this and i click on one image, this is added twice

Comment: hang on not sure with your However.. is your code solving that or are you saying it will never be emptied so it won't ever work?

Comment: well I don't know tbh, the second time I run this, it is adding twice the new selected el

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).hasClass('checked')
```

if this is true you would remove 1 element from the array, it won't matter if it exists or not because

```
urls.splice(urls.indexOf(src), 1)
```

would remove an element even if

```
urls.indexOf(src)
```

returns -1

if you want to fix this you can check

```
if(urls.indexOf(src) != -1){
    urls.splice(urls.indexOf(src), 1)
}
```

Comment: where would I put that then? After the first question mark?

Comment: this condition?, just check if $(this).hasClass('checked') is true and this condition is true then only splice

Comment: so is it basically what the other answer said? because if it is so it is adding twice the same image the second time I call it

Comment: urls.indexOf(src) would search for src in the array, if src was in fact the element you pushed then it would get spliced, if your goal is to handle duplicate data then you just don't need to add it to the array

Comment: thing is the first time i click on an image it is added ok, but then second time i run this (it is within a function), it is adding the same image twice

Comment: urls.push('<div class="card"><img class="img-fluid" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="' + src+ '"></div>' ) this pushes a string which has src as a subpart and then you are looking for src in the array, which it will never find hence it is added twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152466/discussion-between-rob-m-and-marvel308).